# Generate .pyi file which includes docstrings for .pyd binaries

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, docstring, pylance

I recently compiled opencv from source and am currently trying to get autocompletion and tooltips to work on vscode while using pylance language server. Unfortunately pylance does not support `.pyd` binary files. As a temporary solution i figured i could use a stub file so i generated one using the mypy stubgen tool. But the latter does not include doctrings which is why im asking the following question .

The stub file generated should have the following format :

```
def imread(*args, **kwargs) -> Any: 
   '''here goes the imread.__doc__'''
   ...
```

I could use the jedi language server but it does not have semantic highlighting feature which i also really need.

*(i wouldnt mind if you can also point me to a more robust fix for this autocompletion/tooltips issue for opencv)*

Comment: There is an issue for this: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/11965